# How to calculate $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+ax+b)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> What is $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+ax+b)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Starting with a very non-trivial analysis question, this is what I have managed to boil it down to. I do not know the standard computation procedure, substitutions for this type of integrand.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: [Here you go!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108427/integral-int-fracdyy2-ay-b3-2?noredirect=1) Also see [Euler's substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks :)